# Center the header title in drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

[image][image]I am trying to center the title with Drawer Navigation. It's default behaviour on ios is center but for android it is moving to the left side just by the drawer. How to make it to the center of the navigation bar.
I have tried different options provided in the documentation but nothing helped. This is giving almost center appearance on both ios and android but it is not fail proof.

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  const screenOptionsProps = {
      screenOptions: {
      headerTitle: () => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
                height: dimensions.height * 0.1,
                width: dimensions.width - dimensions.width * 0.36,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text>Title</Text>
          </View>
        );
      },
    },
  }
  };
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      {...screenOptionsProps}
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Check below code:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerMenu {...props} />}
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: true,
    drawerActiveBackgroundColor: Colors.ActiveBackgroundColor,
    drawerActiveTintColor: Colors.ActiveTintColor,
    drawerInactiveTintColor: Colors.InactiveTintColor,
    drawerLabelStyle: {
      marginLeft: -2,
      fontSize: 15,
    },
    drawerType: "slide",
    headerStyle: {
      height: 60, // Specify the height of your custom header
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
    },

    headerTitle: "title",
    // HERE IS THIS MAGIC LINE OF CODE

    headerTitleAlign: "center",

    // THAT'S ALL YOU NEED IN DN6 :)

    headerRight: () => (
      <Button
        onPress={() => alert("This is a button!")}
        title="Info"
        color="#fff"
      />
    ),
  }}
>
```

Comment: I was using headerRight on Drawer.Screen instead of Drawe.Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center all of your titles you can use following parameters.

```
 const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
 }, 
 {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Aligned Center',
      headerTitleAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

For specific screen, you can use the following,

```
<AppStack.Screen
              name="MyScreen"
              component={MyComponent}
              options={{
                headerShown: true,
                headerStyle: {
                    textAlign:"center", 
                    flex:1 
                },
            
              }}
            />
```

Comment: I am using DrawerNavigator and these options are not available for it

Answer (score 0):

headerTitleAlign property worked for aligning Title

```
screenOptionsProps = {
      screenOptions: {
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTitle: () => {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
                height: dimensions.height * 0.1,
                width: dimensions.width - dimensions.width * 0.36,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text>Title</Text>
          </View>
        );
      },
    },
  }
```